# Putting an image next to a div block

Tags: html, css

I've been working on my site for about a week or so, and today I've had some trouble putting an image next to a div block. I've tried messing with the display: several times, but it doesn't give me any results.

```
    #indexPic {
  margin-left: 51%;
  }

#whiteBox2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 24%;
  }

  #rainbowdiv1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #rainbowdiv2 {
      margin-left: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      }

 #introtext {
   margin-left: 115px;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   }

   #extintro {
     margin-left: 70px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     }
```

```
<div id="whiteBox2">

<img id="rainbowdiv1" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/b8bcbd7471af04030ae8d6a782d4bdb9/tumblr_oceahwkbFj1vd6nw3o10_500.gifv" alt="A flashy rainbow star divider." width="302" height="8">

<p id="introtext">jeremy . 16 . she/her</p>
<p id="extintro">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </p>
<img id="rainbowdiv2" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/b8bcbd7471af04030ae8d6a782d4bdb9/tumblr_oceahwkbFj1vd6nw3o10_500.gifv" alt="A flashy rainbow star divider." width="302" height="8">
</div>
<img id="indexPic" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/7cba5035b14f88c9b76b6b7263fc9268/tumblr_plx1skKq6D1uo5v6f_1280.png" alt="An edited, rainbowcored version of Rimi Ushigome's Dreamfest card from BanG DREAM!! Girls Band Party." width="200" height="200">


<img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/20dc40b763cbcab5b3f9eeb9cdcd4527/tumblr_pylupn2B431yqo9zko1_400.gifv" class="center">
```

ignore the text spam, it's only a placeholder. any extra tips on ways to improve/fix my code are appreciated!!

Comment: How I would go about it is by wrapping the elements inside of a div tag and then using grid, flex or ig float works too. Can you show a pic of what you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.  I wrapped your image into a div and assigned it the class `pic1`.  I then set it to `float: left;` (I also gave it a margin on top to make it a little more center vertically but this is optional. I also set your `#whiteBox2` to `display: inline-block;` Take a look. Hopefully this works for you.

```css
   #indexPic {
  margin-left: 51%;
  }

#whiteBox2 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  }

  #rainbowdiv1 {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }

    #rainbowdiv2 {
      margin-left: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      }

 #introtext {
   margin-left: 115px;
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   }

   #extintro {
     margin-left: 70px;
     margin-top: 1px;
     }
     
     .pic1 {
       float: left;
       margin-top: 50px;
     }
```

```html
<div id="whiteBox2">

<img id="rainbowdiv1" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/b8bcbd7471af04030ae8d6a782d4bdb9/tumblr_oceahwkbFj1vd6nw3o10_500.gifv" alt="A flashy rainbow star divider." width="302" height="8">

<p id="introtext">jeremy . 16 . she/her</p>
<p id="extintro">TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT <br>
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT </p>
<img id="rainbowdiv2" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/b8bcbd7471af04030ae8d6a782d4bdb9/tumblr_oceahwkbFj1vd6nw3o10_500.gifv" alt="A flashy rainbow star divider." width="302" height="8">
</div>
<div class="pic1">
<img id="indexPic" src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/7cba5035b14f88c9b76b6b7263fc9268/tumblr_plx1skKq6D1uo5v6f_1280.png" alt="An edited, rainbowcored version of Rimi Ushigome's Dreamfest card from BanG DREAM!! Girls Band Party." width="200" height="200">
</div>

<img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/20dc40b763cbcab5b3f9eeb9cdcd4527/tumblr_pylupn2B431yqo9zko1_400.gifv" class="center">
```

Comment: Great! glad to have helped